# Is there a user-friendly Log4Net log files viewer?

Tags: .net, log4net

Is there any third party tool that can recognize Log4Net log file structure and show it in a user friendly way by providing search functionalities etc?

Comment: Here's another one: http://www.log4view.com/log4view/ I've used it for several years and like it.

Comment: Check this side: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tools

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [GamutLogViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gamutlogviewer/).

> GamutLogViewer© is log file, logfile, viewer that works with Log4J, Log4Net, NLog, and user defined formats including ColdFusion. It supports filtering, searching, highlighting and many other useful features. This is a Windows application.

Comment: I prefer and recommend: http://yalv.codeplex.com/

Comment: yalv.codeplex.com requires log files to be in XML format

Comment: Note that log4net does allow you to output log files to XML using:
<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">

Comment: The free version now contains lots of advertisements for the paid version.

Comment: no column filters in the free version

Comment: In the free version, each line of an exception stack trace is displayed on its own line in the log view. So each exception fills 30 or so lines. Extremely annoying.

Comment: And here is another one called  LogViewer4Log4Net [https://github.com/rhessinger/LogViewerForLog4Net]

Comment: yalv moved here:  https://github.com/LukePet/YALV

Comment: GamutLogViewer is no longer commercially available. I purchased a license some time ago and the  website is now offline.  I like it because it was able to read the non-standard ColdFusion log files.

Answer (score 10):

[BareTail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) is a very nice tool to monitor log files.

You can monitor multiple log files, and the Pro version supports search.

Comment: I've got BareTail right here and I see no way to search anything. Is that in the paid version only?

Comment: @PandaWood We used the paid version so i think it won't be included in the free version. If i'm interested in some someware like that i'd try to find a way to use the full version(maybe if you know someone who has .... ) :) and if you like it buy a license.

Answer (score 7):

This one looks promising:
http://yourlog4netviewer.codeplex.com/

Saw this one as well:
http://logexpert.codeplex.com/

Edited: this one as well:
http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: yourlog4netviewer requires changing your output to XML. While that may technically be easy, it may also be undesirable to impossible depending on your circumstances (it's unusable for me)

Comment: logexpert is nice. It can perform actions based on regex matches or logfile rows, such as colour highlighting or even starting other processes!

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look into Apache Chainsaw. It was designed for log4J which is what log4net was ported from so the two will work very well together

http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/

You can display log messages directly to it via a UDP appender or log to an xml file that chainsaw can read.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/howto/chainsaw.html

Comment: There is a new version of Chainsaw in the works with a ton of additional features and improved usability - developer snapshot available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try this one: http://www.l4ndash.com/.
It's web based and the developer version is free but restricted to use on one machine and can be accessed from the same machine.