# How can I paint a string in text file using C#?

Tags: c#, string, colors, textcolor

My program is generating a log, adding strings line by line. Final output (log file) is ending with .txt extension.

There are 3 types of lines: **ERROR**, **WARNING** and **INFO**.

I want to make the ERROR lines to be red, WARNING lines to be yellow, and INFO lines to be green. I'm working in C# and I am using Visual Studio Code.

**How could I possibly do that kind of coloring?**

NOTE: If I have to change the format of log file (not to be .txt anymore), I am okay with that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think that you can change color inside .txt file, so that is not an option.

Comment: You can't change the color of text in a txt file.

Comment: You mean you want a text editor to visualize your log files? Which logger are you using? Log4J, Log4Net, ...?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577568/is-there-a-user-friendly-log4net-log-files-viewer

Comment: Try some other file type or keep 3 separate logs like ErrorLog WarningLog etc

Comment: You cannot put color to your text in *.txt. However, you can  try a few options like create your own txt file viewer that detects these keywords and display with rich text box with colors. Otherwise, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347587/how-to-create-rtf-from-plain-text-or-string-in-c

Comment: .txt won't work. You need something like .rtf.

Comment: Rich Text Format/HTML are the simplest file formats that support colours like that.  Your 3 categories match those of the Windows Event Log so you could use that facility.

Comment: depends how you need it, ansi colour  commands can be inserted into text  files, however, most windows apps do not handle ansi colours by default.

Comment: In my program there are hard-coded strings for each message type, and when an error occurs - it just goes like: log.addLine(type: error, **message**: <what_exactly happened>)

so in log.txt (output) it shows up like this:

ERROR: [timestamp] Error occurred! Message: **<message>**

Well, I want this line to be red colored, if possible. If I have to change the type of log file, it is okay, I will. I am just struggling with how to paint the whole line. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put color in text file. If you have to, you could log into html and use the possibilities of html & css for coloring and formatting.
see [Simple text to HTML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991840/simple-text-to-html-conversion).